# Help with Outlook and SharePoint syncronization

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, outlook, sync

I am aware that the sync to Outlook feature in SharePoint is being removed this year, but does that mean there is going to be a better way to bring tasks, contacts, calendars, etc. together with Outlook? Is there another alternative to do this with an add on or Outlook plugin? Our company relies on this synchronization and need to know if SharePoint is no longer useful to us.